# MemoryStream to sbyte[]

Tags: c#, .net, memorystream

I'm still trying to add a jpeg image to a person in Open LDAP, using Novell's c# libraries:

[Openldap: Add jpegPhoto to inetOrgPerson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930887/openldap-add-jpegphoto-to-inetorgperson)

There is a constructor for Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapAttribute the with the following signature:

```
public LdapAttribute(string attrName, sbyte[] attrBytes)
```

So, I plan to use this one. But, how to convert a jpeg image from a MemoreyStream to sbyte[]?

```
MemoryStream.ToArray()
```

method returns byte[] and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the array like this:

```
Array.ConvertAll(bytes, b => (sbyte)b)
```

Comment: Much better than my `MemoryStream.ToArray().Select(a=>(sbyte)a).ToArray()` idea I was going to post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in the original array there are values greater than 127. What will happen? Will cause errors? The conversion won't make the image unreadable?

Comment: @Oscar: They will be viewed as negative numbers; the underlying bytes will not change.  This must be done in an `unchecked` context.

Comment: Actually, the C# `byte` is unsigned - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @DavidCrowell: That's exactly why he's asking this.

Answer (score 1):

On the CLR you can constant-time convert a `byte[]` to an `sbyte[]`. [See my previous answer on this little-known trick.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11977050/122718)

```
(sbyte[])(object)MemoryStream.ToArray(); //compiles and runs
```